# finding Office 365 activation info

Tags: office365

I have Office365 installed on my old laptop. I have been using it for years, and to the best of my knowledge it is fully activated and legal, but I don't remember how I activated it, whether it was with some email account I don't remember, or I bought a physical license, or what. I now have a new laptop and want to transfer the activation to there, but don't know how to.

This is my "Account" page in Word:

[image]

Comment: You activate Office 365 by logging into the Microsoft Account that has a license to Office 365.  Based on your screenshot you were logged into a Microsoft Account, but likely were logged out, which is the reason Office is prompting you to log into your account.

Comment: @Ramhound That is the problem. I don't know which account had the license. It is not the one I am using now

Comment: Given it's an Enterprise installation it's likely your work email.  **Office 365 doesn't even have a product key, any key you used, was for the subscription itself.**  Office 365's activation status is entirely based on your subscription status.

Comment: "I don't know which account had the license. It is not the one I am using now"   <-- You need the receipt or information from your company and inquire through Microsoft Sales Support.

Answer (score 0):

It implies it is activated (does not say otherwise). So you very likely used a Microsoft Account (your email address) to set it up and activate it.

Go here (Microsoft Account Login Page).

https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-gb

Log in with your email address, and then (if you cannot remember that password), click on Forgot Password and make a new one.

Once you have a new password, you can sign into any Office app and it will show you that you are signed in.

It should be fairly easy to do.

You may need your sales receipt or other information if you do not remember which account you used.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this article is helpful.

[You forgot your Microsoft account username](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/you-forgot-your-microsoft-account-username-b2049472-3b8f-27d3-61c6-67a668453f4c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

I also suggest you go to Registry Editor, locate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities`, check whether there is any email address shown.

[image]